# Flagging feature in SharePoint

Tags: wss-3.0

Is the 'Flagging' (like we have in MS Outlook) feature available for WSS 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if there is an option to flag an item to create a follow-up task then the answer is no.

If you have a custom or third party tagging feature then it is possible.

Comment: Can you please list any 3rd party tagging features..

Comment: here is one:  http://www.kwizcom.com/ProductPage.asp?ProductID=517&ProductSubNodeID=518

Comment: Is there a free option available?

Comment: There were some projects on CodePlex, but I think they were all in Alpha or Beta testing and since the features are part of the 2010 product there isn't any additional work being done.

Comment: Currently using simple YES/NO checkboxes to flag :)